# How to allow Root Level search for LDAP in SpagoBI

Tags: ldap, spagobi

I have connected ldap with my spagobi usiing ldap_authentication.xml
It works fine.
The point is that I need to provide "ou" name and it will search fr the user in the given ""ou' it self, even it does not performs Root Level Search.

In My case,I have lots of ou's in my DC.
And all the users are in different ou's
And I would like to keep default DC name as path in xml file and would like to change search method to ROOT_Level Search.
So please help me that how can I perform sub-directory searches using spagobi.